# Compiling Code in Medium Trust

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation, razor

Together with Ben (@BuildStarted), we've been building the [RazorEngine project](http://razorengine.codeplex.com), which is designed to allow you compile and parse arbitrary templates outside of ASP.NET MVC.  The project has had a couple of releases for a while now, and the feedback has been great (thanks to all!). **But**, we have encountered an issue: Medium trust.

Because we are using the CSharpCodeProvider to compile the Razor-generated classes (to load into the current AppDomain for execution), we encounter a `SecurityException` when trying to invoke it, due to the LinkDemand enforced on it.  When a normal ASP.NET page is compiled (regardless of trust level), it does so through a `BuildProvider` which is normally GAC'd, and thus is implicity granted the appropriate permissions to compile.  Hence ASP.NET WebForms works as standard in Medium trust.

Our code does not, and we need to target scenarios where our built library won't be deployed to the GAC and is running in Medium trust. So we considered building a `BuildProvider` specifically for it and defer compilation to the ASP.NET build system, but this seems overly complex and disjointed, and the provider itself requires both a mapping through a file extension, and a virtual path (which may or may not resolve to a physical file - think `VirtualPathProvider`).  It all seems overkill, just to get the project working in Medium trust; not just that, but purely for ASP.NET projects as our engine also works outside of ASP.NET

So my question is this, does anyone know of any techniques or technologies for compiling C# code in a Medium trust environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider using MCS (Mono Compiler Service), which has the possibility to emit to an in memory assembly instead of a file (yes, I know CSharpCodeProvider has the ability for in memory only, but it still writes temp files and performs file system operations).

Caveat: You'll probably run into security issues with MCS too, but it's open source (obviously) and I've been able to modify it so as to do expression compilation in Silverlight... Just saying, it's probably not going to be a piece of cake.

Update: Per the Mono roadmap page, my modifications aren't really necessary anymore since they say they support Silverlight out of the box in version 2.8.

Comment: I've considered that route but I wanted to definitely stay with built in the more official stuff at this point - However, I'm still open to that and if I can't find a solution that satisfies our needs I'm sure we'll consider it again.

Comment: In my experience, CodeDom is pretty painful in almost every respect. And if you're planning on doing any kind of bulk compilation...unless you want to maintain and recycle a separate AppDomain, CodeDom is 100% out of the question.

Comment: Also...bear in mind CodeDom/CSharpCodeProvider has no problem spitting out to a string, which you could feed into an alternative compiler (MCS).

Comment: Just to update on this answer. You are correct that there are security issues. I will continue to explore this answer :)

Comment: @JeffN825: Thanks the suggestion, unfortunately we don't have any control over how Razor is generating code, unless of course we forked Razor itself to change the underlying code generation.  In the end, we stuck with the BuildProvider model.  Thanks again.

Comment: True...but is it the Razr generated code that's causing your security problems or is it the compilation? Also, doesn't the generated code get returned to you in a CodeDom object model...? So you could change the code prior to compilation, no?

Comment: Yeah, its the instantiation of the CodeDomProvider that is required to compile the generated code, it explicitly requires Full Trust.